# How to uninstall ruby installed by ruby-install

Tags: ruby, ruby-install

I have many rubies installed by [ruby-install](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install) under `~/.rubies`:

```
ls .rubies
ruby-1.9.3-p545 ruby-2.0.0-p598 ruby-2.1.3      ruby-2.1.5
ruby-2.0.0-p451 ruby-2.1.2      ruby-2.1.4      ruby-2.2.0
```

I want to uninstall one of the ruby installed by ruby-install, How do I do that?

Comment: Are you using Linux? If yes, which distro? Are you using `rvm`, `rbenv` or any other ruby version manager?

Comment: Does it matter which OS? I use OS X and I don't use any tools except ruby-install and chruby.

Comment: Yes, it matters a lot. While on Linux you can completely remove Ruby, Apple includes Ruby starting at Snow Leopard and has code calling it from apps. I've upvoted your question if the OS matters, because it's frequent and really important :)

Comment: I did not want to completely remove Ruby, just want to remove one version of Ruby installed by ruby-install. And I did not want to remove system Ruby. Sorry I did not state clearly from my question. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 25):

Unfortunately appears that `ruby-install` just downloads and compiles Ruby, with no option to remove it, unlike `RVM` or `rbenv`.

So, probably you'll need to run some manual commands here to delete all installed files.

### 1. Locate it

Usually `ruby-install` will install rubies in `~/.rubies/` folder.

If you're not sure which ruby was installed using `ruby-install`, locate the file `.installed.list`, as it has a list of installed files during Ruby install. If you want to quickly locate it, just run `locate .installed.list` and you'll get a short list of them.

Then run a `cat` on the file located at the version you want to remove, to make sure which is the root folder for the ruby install you want to delete.

### 2. Remove it

Then you can just remove the folder where the target version is located.

If you want to remove `ruby-1.9.3-p545`, run:

```
rm -Rf ~/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545
```

### 3. Installed gems

If you want to remove installed gems, usually they're located at `~/.gem/ruby/`.

Comment: You'll also need to clear out the installed gems as well. For me they are in `~/.gem/ruby/*`.

Comment: And then to update the list of rubies that `chruby` reports, either open a new shell or run `source /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh`.  See https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install/issues/135

Comment: Removing the directory seems to be the [documented](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install#readme) `ruby-install` way.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the responses in a [feature request](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install/issues/269), the best way to remove older ruby versions is to go back to the `src` directory and run `make uninstall` or `rake uninstall`.  By default, `ruby-install` uses `$HOME/src/ruby-$version` for unpacked sources of ruby versions during installation.

For example, removing ruby version 2.6.3:

```
cd $HOME/src/ruby-2.6.3/ && make uninstall
```

Unfortunately, even though this bug/request was opened in 2016, this feature is still not implemented in `ruby-install`.

If you've installed the ruby version using the default locations, then you should be safe by removing the specific subfolder within `$HOME/.rubies/`.

```
rm -rf $HOME/.rubies/ruby-2.6.3
```

It's worth noting that it may be necessary to manually remove any gems installed with that ruby version.

e.g.

```
rm -rf $HOME/.gem/ruby/ruby-2.6.3
```

Comment: In my case a `gem update` corrupted my 2.7.2 version. Removing (`rm -rf`) the `~/.rubies/ruby-2.7.2` and `~/.gem/ruby/ruby-2.7.2` and then reinstalling with `ruby-install --src-dir ~/src/ruby-install ruby 2.7.2` worked for me. My setup: `Ubuntu 20.04`, using https://brew.sh for `ruby-install` and `chruby` installs

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem with my lubuntu virtual machine! I went into the shell from the login screen (by pressing `CNTR + ALT + F3`) and checked the versions of ruby and gem:

`ruby -v`
`gem -v`

then I run `sudo apt-get purge -y ruby` as suggested by chad. It successfully removed both ruby and gem.

Then I rebooted with:

`reboot`

And I was able to log in normally again!

Answer (score 2):

If you installed package 2.3x(+) and you need to uninstall it, there is an uninstall executable inside of the root directory. Go to C:/ and you'll see the ruby folder there, inside it there will be the unin.exe. This all depends on where you chose to install it.

Answer (score 1):

You just remove where the ruby is.

For example, uninstall ruby that installed by ruby-install (default installation location is `~/.rubies`):

```
rm ~/.rubies/ruby-2.2.0
```

If you see this kind of error after removed Ruby 2.2.0-preview2 and installed Ruby 2.2.0-p0 for example:

```
$ bundle -v
zsh: /Users/Juan/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/bin/bundle: bad interpreter:
     /Users/Juan/.rubies/ruby-2.2.0-preview2/bin/ruby: no such file or directory
```

You need to run

```
gem pristin --only-executables
```

Because whenever a ruby is updated or perhaps moved/named, due to RubyGems is generating explicit `#!/path/to/ruby` for all gem executables, will need to regenerate the gem bin stubs with the new path to the ruby executable.

Answer (score 1):

if you install soft by dpkg or yum, when to uninstall it, you also should use dpkg or yum to purge it.

for example,  we want to unintall fcitx,

> sudo apt-get purge -y fcitx

otherwise, the soft install manually, use configuration && make && make install , just remove the directory installed when you uninstall it.

for you example. just

> rm -rf ~/.rubies/ruby-2.2.0

if you have doubts that is the target ruby remove clearly, just use find command to confirm.

> find ~/ -name  "*ruby-2.2.0*"

Comment: Thank you. But I mentioned that Ruby was installed by ruby-install.

Answer (score 0):

Removes all associated ruby packages

sudo apt remove ruby

Comment: After run sudo apt autoremove

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

To uninstall Ruby installed by ruby-install, you can follow these steps:

1. **Locate the Ruby installation directory.** Ruby-install typically installs Rubies in the `~/.rubies/` folder. You can check the exact location by running the following command:

```
ruby-install list
```

This will list all of the Ruby installations managed by ruby-install.

2. **Uninstall the Ruby installation.** Once you have located the Ruby installation directory, you can uninstall it by running the following command:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.rubies/<version>
```

Replace `<version>` with the version of Ruby that you want to uninstall.

3. **Remove any installed gems.** If you have any gems installed for the Ruby version that you are uninstalling, you can remove them by running the following command:

```
gem uninstall -a --all-versions --system | grep -v '^Already uninstalled'
```

This will uninstall all of the gems installed for the specified Ruby version.

4. **Remove the ruby-install cache.** If you want to remove the ruby-install cache, you can run the following command:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.cache/ruby-install
```

This will remove all of the Ruby installation files that are cached by ruby-install.

**Important:** Be careful when uninstalling Ruby, as it may remove other dependencies that are installed on your system. It is always a good idea to back up your system before uninstalling any software.