# Rails uninitialized constant Rack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I tried to setup a rails 5.0.0 app following [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) on ubuntu 16.04, when I start `rails server` for the first time, it crashed with the following message.
I am new to ruby and do not know what is wrong

`/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:8:in <module:Rails>': uninitialized constant Rack (NameError)
Did you mean?  Rake
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:7:in <top (required)>'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:138:in require'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:138:in require_command!'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:83:in server'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in run_command!'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in <top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in require'
from bin/rails:4:in <main>'`

and here is the first 10 lines of

`/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb`

```
require 'fileutils'
require 'optparse'
require 'action_dispatch'
require 'rails'
require 'rails/dev_caching'

module Rails
  class Server < ::Rack::Server
    class Options
      DEFAULT_PID_PATH = File.expand_path("tmp/pids/server.pid").freeze
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try these commands on your project path;

```
bundle update

gem update
```

Comment: After i tried the commands above(eh..`sudo gem update` instead of `gem update` because some errors), it crashed again with the same message :-(

Comment: Just remove all of them with `sudo apt-get purge ruby rubygems` then re-install  them.

Comment: consider using a ruby version manager instead of using the system ruby for development. Good one are rvm rbenv switch-ruby etc..

Comment: **Caution** `gem update` corrupted my `ruby-install`ed 2.7.2 version and I had to reinstall it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57177186/960184

Comment: remove all gems and reinstall ```gem uinistall -aIx```