# how to completely uninstall ruby if it has been install as a system at a Mac?

Tags: ruby

I has been install a ruby version 3.1.2 at my Mac computer and I want to uninstall it completely.

When I check by this command

```
which -a ruby
```

It show me this

```
/Users/nguyencuc/.rubies/ruby-3.1.2/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

So, as this page said, https://mac.install.guide/ruby/9.html, maybe it is a system ruby ?

So how can I completely uninstall this ruby to install another version of ruby ? Could you please give me some advices ? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: @Stefan I installed it by this command : brew install rbenv ruby-build

Comment: For `rbenv` / `ruby-build` see https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#uninstalling-ruby-versions. However, your directory (`~/.rubies`) looks more like an installation from `chruby` / `ruby-install`. If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27665381/how-to-uninstall-ruby-installed-by-ruby-install

Answer (score 4):

As you have installed ruby, not using rbenv or rvm, there are two ways through which you can remove it.

1. Using Command  `brew uninstall --force ruby`
2. Or you have to manually remove the ruby files from your system. Type `whereis ruby` to find where it is installed and then remove the files using `rm`

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed ruby via Rbenv, type this:

```
rbenv uninstall 3.1.2
```

For installing another version, type:

```
 rbenv install *version*
```